# How Should Convert SQL to MYSQL FOR XML AUTO CODE?

Tags: mysql, sql, xml

I need to convert an XML Auto Code to MYSQL code. Below is sample sql code which need to convert in mysql.

**SQL Code-:**

SELECT
*
FROM
Table1
WHERE
Column1 = @param1
AND
column2 <= @param2
AND
Cloumn3 <= @param3
ORDER BY
Column2 DESC,
Column3 DESC
FOR
XML AUTO

Comment: You have to be more specific. At least show us what you have and what you've tried.

Comment: `Auto Code` accesses the query data source metadata. There is no such service in MySQL.

Comment: It doesn't look like it needs conversion. Provided that all `@paramX` values (or variables) are defined, you just need to remove `FOR XML AUTO` and you can run that query in MySQL, right?

Comment: above code returns result from stored procedure so output fetch should be result in XML Structure